# Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two variables, Date and Taxa and want to get the date for the first time each taxa occurs.  There are 9 different dates and 40 different taxa in the data frame consisting of 172 rows, but my answer should only have 40 rows.

Taxa is a factor and Date is a date.

For example, my data frame (called 'species') is set up like this:

```
Date          Taxa
2013-07-12    A
2011-08-31    B
2012-09-06    C
2012-05-17    A
2013-07-12    C
2012-09-07    B
```

and I would be looking for an answer like this:

```
Date          Taxa
2012-05-17    A
2011-08-31    B
2012-09-06    C
```

I tried using:

```
t.first <-  species[unique(species$Taxa),]
```

and it gave me the correct number of rows but there were Taxa repeated.  If I just use unique(species$Taxa) it appears to give me the right answer, but then I don't know the date when it first occurred.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
t.first <- species[match(unique(species$Taxa), species$Taxa),]
```

should give you what you're looking for. `match` returns indices of the first match in the compared vectors, which give you the rows you need.

Comment: For this to work, you must first ensure your data frame is sorted by whichever column determines the "first" instance.  This can be done using `species[with(species, order(Date)), ]` as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns)

Answer (score 20):

In the following command, `duplicated` creates a logical index for duplicated `data$Taxa` values. A subset of the data frame without the corresponding rows is created with:

```
data[!duplicated(data$Taxa), ]
```

The result:

```
        Date Taxa
1 2012-05-17    A
2 2011-08-31    B
3 2012-09-06    C
```

Comment: For this to work, you must first ensure your data frame is sorted by whichever column determines the "first" instance.  This can be done using `species[with(species, order(Date)), ]` as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns)

Comment: I have a simple case where I don't care which one I want to select -- so this will work well for me without ordering first.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck If you don't care which one you want to select, the order is irrelevant. You can use this technique.

Comment: Yes we are saying the same thing sir!

Answer (score 15):

Here is a `dplyr` option that is not dependent on the data being sorted in date order and accounts for ties:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Taxa) %>% 
  filter(Date == min(Date)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% # takes the first occurrence if there is a tie
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Date       Taxa 
  <date>     <chr>
1 2012-05-17 A    
2 2011-08-31 B    
3 2012-09-06 C 

# sample data:
df <- read.table(text = 'Date          Taxa
                         2013-07-12    A
                         2011-08-31    B
                         2012-09-06    C
                         2012-05-17    A
                         2013-07-12    C
                         2012-09-07    B', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And you could get the same by sorting by date as well:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Taxa) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(species)
species[, .SD[which.min(Date)], by = Taxa]
#    Taxa       Date
# 1:    A 2012-05-17
# 2:    B 2011-08-31
# 3:    C 2012-09-06
```

*Data:*

```
species <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2013-07-12", "2011-08-31", "2012-09-06", 
                   "2012-05-17", "2013-07-12", "2012-09-07")), 
  Taxa = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
# Create some dummy data:

# Create some dates 
Date=as.POSIXct(c("2013-07-12","2011-08-31","2012-09-06","2009-01-01",
                  "2012-05-17","2013-07-12","2012-09-07","2013-02-02"))

# Create unique taxa
Taxa=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),2)

# Combine the two into a dataframe
data=as.data.frame(list(Date=Date,Taxa=Taxa))

# this returns a numeric vector of the minimum dates
xx=tapply(data$Date,list(data$Taxa),min)

# And this will return a dataframe with the first occurence
# of your taxa (or variables)
as.data.frame(list(Date=as.POSIXct(xx,origin="1970-01-01"),
                   Taxa=names(xx)))
```

Note: You can add simplify=T in tapply to return a POSIXt
 object but it returns a list. More info can be found here: 
[Unexpected behaviour of min, tapply and POSIXct/POSIXlt classes?](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Unexpected-behabiour-of-min-tapply-and-POSIXct-POSIXlt-classes-td3017691.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. First of all, I want to highlight that the output you've mentioned is not correct as per your requirement. It should be:

```
Date          Taxa
2013-07-12    A
2011-08-31    B
2012-09-06    C
```

i.e., the first entry was not correct. Now talking about the code for this, all these are good answers but the solution I propose is more robust.
To demonstrate better, I have used a new dataframe.

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(rep("A", 4), c(rep("B",4)), rep("C",4)), b=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1))
d %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = detect_index(.x = b, .f = p), d = row_number()) %>% mutate(e = ifelse(c==d,1,0)) %>% ungroup()
```

Keep Coding!