# How to find the first and last occurrence in a panel data set in R

Tags: r

I have a table:

```
id  time
1   1
1   2
1   5
2   3
2   2
2   7
3   8
3   3
3   14
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
id  first last
1      1     5
2      3     7
3      8    14
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944334/extract-rows-for-the-first-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 5):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', we get the `first` and `last` value of 'time'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(firstocc = time[1L], lastocc = time[.N]),
                    by = id]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we use the same methodology.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(firstocc = first(time), lastocc = last(time))
```

---

Or with `base R` (no packages needed)

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, df1$id), 
    function(x) data.frame(id = x$id[1],
       firstocc = x$time[1], lastocc = x$time[nrow(x)])))
```

---

If we need to be based on the `min` and `max` values (not related to the expected output) , the `data.table` option is

```
setDT(df1)[, setNames(as.list(range(time)),
                 c('firstOcc', 'lastOcc')) ,id]
```

and `dplyr` is

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(firstocc = min(time), lastocc = max(time))
```

Comment: When you group by id I don't want to order id. I want to let it be in the order it is in. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @PreetRajdeo  You can convert the 'id' to `factor` class and set the levels iin the same order.  i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(id = factor(id, levels = unique(id))) %>% summarise(firstocc = min(time), lastocc = max(time))`

Answer (score 3):

There are many packages that can perform aggregation of this sort in R.  We show how to do it without any packages and then show it with some packages.

**1)** Use `aggregate`.  No packages needed.

```
ag <- aggregate(time ~ id, DF, function(x) c(first = min(x), last = max(x)))
```

giving:

```
> ag
  id time.first time.last
1  1          1         5
2  2          2         7
3  3          3        14
```

`ag` is a two column data frame whose second column contains a two column matrix with columns named 'first' and 'last'.  If you want to flatten it to a 3 column data frame use:

```
do.call("cbind", ag)
```

giving:

```
     id first last
[1,]  1     1    5
[2,]  2     2    7
[3,]  3     3   14
```

**1a)** This variation of (1) is more compact at the expense of uglier column names.

```
aggregate(time ~ id, DF, range)
```

**2) sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select id, min(time) first, max(time) last from DF group by id")
```

giving:

```
     id first last
[1,]  1     1    5
[2,]  2     2    7
[3,]  3     3   14
```

**3) summaryBy** summaryBy in the doBy package is much like `aggregate`:

```
library(doBy)

summaryBy(time ~ id, data = DF, FUN = c(min, max))
```

giving:

```
  id time.min time.max
1  1        1        5
2  2        2        7
3  3        3       14
```

**Note:** Here is the input `DF` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "id  time
1   1
1   2
1   5
2   3
2   2
2   7
3   8
3   3
3   14"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

**Update:**  Added (1a), (2) and (3) and fixed (1).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicates and reshape it

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "id  time
1   1
1   2
1   5
2   3
2   2
2   7
3   8
3   3
3   14")

d2 <- dd[!(duplicated(dd$id) & duplicated(dd$id, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
reshape(within(d2, tt <- c('first', 'last')), dir = 'wide', timevar = 'tt')

#   id time.first time.last
# 1  1          1         5
# 4  2          3         7
# 7  3          8        14
```