# Extract first value after a specific observation

Tags: r

I couldn't quite find what I was looking for: this comes closest: [Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944334/extract-rows-for-the-first-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-a-data-frame).

So I'm trying to figure out how I could extract the row directly following a specific observation. So for every year, there will be a place in the data where the observation is "over" and then I want the first numeric value following that "over." How would I do that?

So in the minimal example below, I would want to pluck the "7" (from the threshold variable) which directly follows the "over."

Thanks much!

```
other.values = c(13,10,10,9,8,4,5,7,7,5)
values = c(12,15,16,7,6,4,5,8,8,4)
df = data.frame(values, other.values)%>%mutate(threshold = ifelse(values - other.values > 0, "over", values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(threshold != 'over')) %>%
  filter(lag(threshold) == 'over' & lag(grp) != grp)

#  values other.values threshold grp
#1      7            9         7   2
#2      4            5         4   6
```

Comment: Thanks! so the issue is that there are actual numeric values that appear before the "over"; and the first of these values is what is being returned.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this but surely there is a better way

```
df$threshold[max(which(df$threshold == "over"))+1]
```

Basically, this return the row index of the last match to `"over"` and then adds 1.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

You can subset on those rows `which` do not have the value `over` in `threshold` AND (`&`) `which` do have `over` in the row prior (`lag`):

```
library(dplyr)
df[which(!df$threshold=="over" & lag(df$threshold)=="over"),]
  values other.values threshold
   values other.values threshold
4       7            9         7
10      4            5         4
```

Comment: So there are two issues: the first is that there are actual numeric values that appear before the "over" (which is what is being returned with the code you provided); and then the second issue is that since this repeats every year, I need to find the first value after over for every subsequent year (I suppose I could integrate some kind of for loop here). Thanks!