# Take the earliest mention of a figure from within a range by ID

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar to [Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944334/extract-rows-for-the-first-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-a-data-frame)
Dataset example:

```
ID   grade    date 
A     1        1/1/2001
A     3        1/2/2002 
A     5        2/4/2002
B     4        1/1/2008
B     4        1/1/2010
B     5        1/1/2011
B     5        1/3/2011
B     4        1/5/2011
C     2        1/1/2006
C     5        1/1/2007
C     5        1/1/2008
D     3        1/1/1996
D     5        1/1/1997
D     5        1/1/1999
E     1        1/1/2003
E     3        1/1/2005
E     3        1/1/2007
```

I would like to keep all entries per person until they hit grade 5 and then stop irrespective of grades after the earliest mention of 5. Not all IDs have reached stage 5, they should remain untouched even if they have multiple of the same grade

Desired output:

```
ID   grade    date 
A     1        1/1/2001
A     3        1/2/2002 
A     5        2/4/2002
B     4        1/1/2008
B     4        1/1/2010
B     5        1/1/2011
C     2        1/1/2006
C     5        1/1/2007
D     3        1/1/1996
D     5        1/1/1997
E     1        1/1/2003
E     3        1/1/2005
E     3        1/1/2007
```

I can used order and in dplyr the filter function but I am unsure how to apply these to just the 5's per person and then exclude anything afterwards?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice` to grab the sequence from 1 until the first appearance of 5, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 slice(1L : first(which(grade == 5)[1])) 

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
   ID    grade date    
   <chr> <int> <chr>   
 1 A         1 1/1/2001
 2 A         3 1/2/2002
 3 A         5 2/4/2002
 4 B         4 1/1/2008
 5 B         4 1/1/2010
 6 B         5 1/1/2011
 7 C         2 1/1/2006
 8 C         5 1/1/2007
 9 D         3 1/1/1996
10 D         5 1/1/1997
```

**EDIT**
If you have groups that do NOT have grade = 5, then

```
df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(new = which(grade == 5)[1], 
        new = replace(new, is.na(new), max(row_number()))) %>% 
 slice(1L : first(new)) %>%
 select(-new)

# A tibble: 13 × 4
# Groups:   ID [5]
   ID    grade date       
   <chr> <int> <chr>    
 1 A         1 1/1/2001     
 2 A         3 1/2/2002     
 3 A         5 2/4/2002     
 4 B         4 1/1/2008     
 5 B         4 1/1/2010     
 6 B         5 1/1/2011     
 7 C         2 1/1/2006     
 8 C         5 1/1/2007     
 9 D         3 1/1/1996     
10 D         5 1/1/1997     
11 E         1 1/1/2003     
12 E         3 1/1/2005     
13 E         3 1/1/2007
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. When I do this I get "Error in 1L: first(which(grade== 5)[1]) : NA/NaN argument"

Comment: Do you have IDs with all NAs or without 5?

Comment: Not that I am aware  of but will double check. Not all IDs have a grade 5, some stop earlier if that is useful to know?

Comment: Yes that was it. It couldnt find 5. Let me revise

Comment: Apologies! I can confirm there are no NAs

Comment: I edited my answer. Try and let me know